# How to handle buttons in child components of a Form

Tags: reactjs, components, parent-child, es6-class

I have this component:

```
class ConnectedStepsForm extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    debugger
    //Here is where i am. 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>Datos personales: Paso  {this.props.step}</p>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Step1 />
          <Step2 />
          <Step3 />
          <TabNavButton />
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the parent component, a simple multiplestep component.

In my step3, I have a button to add dynamic fields. So I am using this button to add those fields. The problem is when I click on that button. For some reason, it calls the handleSubmit event from the parent.

```
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert('it works')
  }
  render(){
    if (this.props.step !== 3) {
      return null
    } 
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        {/* Se puede utilizar conditional rendering para cambiar la funcionalidad del boton */}
        <button onClick={this.addField} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>Añadir Contacto</button>
...
```

But, it doesn't work as I expect, it never shows me the alert from the handleSubmit in the child. And that is not the worst part, I have another method in my step3 class, for adding items, and now is impossible for me to access into it...

```
addItem = event => { 
    event.preventDefault() 
    debugger //I want to be here!!
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {list: [...prevState.list, {red:"", name:""}]}
    });
  }
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button doesn't have a `onSubmit` handler, so the function given to the `onSubmit` prop of the form will be called instead.

You could change the handler to `onClick` and change the button type from `submit` which is the default to `button` and the submit handler will not be called.

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.addField}>
  Añadir Contacto
</button>
```